# href mailto not working in Joomla 2.5 module

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I'm setting up a new Joomla 2.5 web, and I've find this problem.

When I use a mailto link in an article, everything works as it expected, but if I do the same in a module, javascript code replace the email.

Some sample source output:

```
<a class="contact-icons mail" href="mailto:
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
var prefix = '&#109;a' + 'i&#108;' + '&#116;o';
var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
var addy21722 = 'example@example.com';
document.write('<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy21722 + '\'>');
document.write(addy21722);
document.write('<\/a>');
//-->\n </script><script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
document.write('<span style=\'display: none;\'>');
//-->
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
document.write('</');
document.write('span>');
//-->
</script>"></a>
```

I can see the problem lays in the obfuscation code, but I can't understand why only fails in a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's the email cloaking that's causing this for you. Read this topic page to find out [more](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1468391).

Comment: Thanks, it really is a obfuscated way of disabling email cloaking. I were searching options in the plugin, but there were none of use.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. The cloaking might be done via a system plugin which you could simply disable if you wanted. This would disable it for the whole site though, something you may not want..